# What's the new method for setting defaults for jQuery UI's dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I've been using the following in UI 1.7, but it doesn't work in 1.8 any more:

```
$.extend($.ui.dialog.defaults, {
    modal: true,
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    minWidth: 500,
    minHeight: 400
});
```

Is there a new method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. The following:

```
$.ui.dialog.defaults
```

...needs to be changed to:

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype.options
```